# Translating custom error messages

Tags: error-handling, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I have a form (using simple_form) which I want to implement support for translated error messages. All my translations appear with the exception of the error message.

My Customer model is:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :phone, :email, :contact_method

  validates_presence_of :phone, :email, :contact_method, :message => I18n.t(:required)
end
```

My `fr.yml` file

```
fr:
  name: 'Nom'
  phone: 'Téléphone'
  email: 'Courriel'
  contact_method: 'Méthode de contact'
  required: 'Requis'
```

My form is as follows:

```
= simple_form_for @customer do |f|
  = f.input :name, label: t(:name)
  = f.input :phone, label: t(:phone)
  = f.input :email, label: t(:email)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you should use a `Symbol` with `validates_presence_of`. Don't translate it with I18n manually:

```
validates_presence_of :phone, :email, :contact_method, :message => :required
```

Secondly, add translation for your error message to your locale file like this:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      customer:
        required: 'Requis'
```