# Translate simple_form error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have this code displaying localized texts:

```
  <%= f.input :full_name, :label => _('registration.form.label.name') + ':', :required => false -%>
  <%= f.input :company, :label => _('registration.form.label.company') + ':', :required => false -%>
```

As you can see, the labels are being translated using the keys and an external system. The label part is working properly. However the error messages ("can't be blank" etc.) are not translated. The easiest way would be to customize the error messages by wrapping them in the _() tag, but I can't seem to find where to do it.

What would be the easiest way to translate the error messages? Preferably using the current translation system.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955208/translating-custom-error-messages) help you?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't really help me much. I am using a uniform translation management system and changing yml files for translating is out of the question. The easiest solution is to find the right variable to wrap in the _() tag and all would be well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to create custom error messages. (Example here: [Customize error message with simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808611/customize-error-message-with-simple-form))

```
validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 5, :message => "blah blah blah"
```

And use them like this:

```
<%= f.input :name, :error_html => { :id => "name_error"} %>
```

Comment: Is this really "THE" solution? I think the goal is to place the messages in the simple form yaml file...

Comment: Sorry, that is the only workaround I found feasible for my purpose.

Comment: Sure, no worries. What do you think of this approach? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36410506/5521564

Comment: This approach would be absolutely fine unless I had a separate translation service. Adding translations to yml files is not feasible for the user as we have a separate system for managing translations.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the error messages to the `activerecord` yaml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      mymodel:
        attributes:
          name:
            too_short: "%{attribute} is too short."
```

This way you can also reference the `attribute` name within your yaml.

Of course, ideally you would place both the label and the validation in the `simple_form` i18n yaml, but I was not able to figure this out. Any suggestions for this are welcome.